# How to achieve LinearLayout title/label

Tags: android, label, android-linearlayout, grouping, title

How to achieve labels/titles for grouping in layout (XML) several inputs in Activity?

Here's screenshot, but I can't find sources/example, the interesting parts are blue PHOTO and EMAIL labels above the inputs (on the left side of screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think you are talking about actionBars Look at this link for doing the same [action bar example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! in the future, it's usually helpful to mention what you've already tried.

Comment: Got the solution with TextView and style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" parameter

Comment: Thanks Corley, I hope to post full answer and photos, but there's a lot of limitations for new users.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Manishika, but there's no info about putting labels into navigation drawer (not action bar).

I suppose, i needed this in my layout:

```
<TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
         style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
         android:text="Phone"
     />
```

just above normal EditText.